# What are rw_settings?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Here is the beginning of my log (v26 of the Bitcoin Core) on Windows :

```
2024-01-21T04:50:15Z Ignoring unknown rw_settings value onion-prev
2024-01-21T04:50:15Z Bitcoin Core version v26.0.0 (release build)
2024-01-21T04:50:15Z Qt 5.15.10 (static), plugin=windows (static)
```

Do you know what means the first line ? I can't find any information.